# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance

I will be grateful if someone can point out where the error is occurring.

```
class hotel extends WishDBxyz{ 
 public nomhotel;
 protected idhotel, ile_idile, pays_idpays, chainehotel_idchainehotel, actif ;
}
```

Just on second line got the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected  (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE). I'm quite new to Object Oriented PHP and writting one class inheriting another class.

Answer (score 7):

Those are variables in php.So add the `$`  sign:

```
class hotel extends WishDBxyz{ 
 public $nomhotel;
 protected $idhotel, $ile_idile, $pays_idpays, $chainehotel_idchainehotel, $actif ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [PHP manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> Variables in PHP are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable. The variable name is case-sensitive.

So for your case, you'd put something like:

```
class Hotel extends WishDBxyz{ 
    public $nomhotel;
    protected $idhotel, $ile_idile, $pays_idpays, $chainehotel_idchainehotel, $actif ;
}
```

For examples on declaring classes, properties, methods, etc., look at the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

(As a habit, I usually use [UpperCamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) for the class name)

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the `$`

public $var;

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 1):

You are missing $ in variables

```
class hotel extends WishDBxyz{ 
 public $nomhotel;
 protected $idhotel, $ile_idile, $pays_idpays, $chainehotel_idchainehotel, $actif ;
}
```

Comment: Any reason for giving this anwser vote  down ? isn,t it explain the answer well ?.

Answer (score 0):

Variable names should be prefixed with $