# Docusign API PHP adding listitem to document causes error

Tags: docusignapi

I am sure I am not the first to encounter this, but I was unable to find a solution while Googling.

I am trying to add a drop-down list to my document. At the top of my model I am adding these namespaces:

```
use \DocuSign\eSign\Model\List; 
use \DocuSign\eSign\Model\ListItem;
```

When doing so I get this error because "List" is a reserved word in PHP.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Parsing Error
Message: syntax error, unexpected List (T_LIST), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
Filename: models/Docusign_model.php
Line Number: 19
```

I tried changing the name of the class from `List` to `Elist` but then I got errors from ObjectSerializer that it could not find `Elist:swaggerType`.

What am I missing on how to add a list to my document?

Thom

Comment: can you show more of your code snippet of adding tabs to the envelope?

Comment: Even without any code to add a list, this fails by just trying to include the line "use \Docusign\eSign\Model\List;" So, I have no code to create the list, just trying to get started by adding the model.

Comment: @thom take a look at my answer below and let us know if this get's you headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

@thom I think this is really a "PHP" parsing question as is answered here for you [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930748/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-string-expecting-variable-t-variable)

So I think the $ missing is your real issue as discussed in the referenced article above and below from PHP Manual.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Recommend you look at GIT example from SDK using CustomFieldList at https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client/blob/ccc86ac37334f34728361d73b2f8c4592225b8d2/src/Model/CustomFieldsEnvelope.php

excerpt

```
    protected static $swaggerTypes = [
    'list_custom_fields' => '\DocuSign\eSign\Model\ListCustomField[]',
    'text_custom_fields' => '\DocuSign\eSign\Model\TextCustomField[]'
];
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Also, maybe the first place to validate if you even need a specific "use" is by reviewing this PHP sample code from a good friend Ergin https://gist.github.com/Ergin008/d4a8b9210fbea41414b0

As I see it with most of the DocuSign SDK's, you have the client and specific services you want to use per excerpt below:

```
    // Download PHP client:  https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-PHP-Client
require_once './DocuSign-PHP-Client/src/DocuSign_Client.php';
require_once './DocuSign-PHP-Client/src/service/DocuSign_RequestSignatureService.php';
require_once './DocuSign-PHP-Client/src/service/DocuSign_ViewsService.php';
```

Regardless if I am right or wrong, let us know if this helped you go in the right direction :-)

Comment: Thanks @David. Yes, certainly is a parsing issue. You probably know more about this than I, but what I see in the example you gave is parsing issues because variable do not that the "$" before them so they are interpreted as a string. In my case my "use" examples (I have about a dozen) all work fine except when I add the one with the file name "List". It is interpreting "List" as a php list, not as a string. I have my APIs working, I am just trying to add a drop-down list to my document, so I am pretty sure I need those two Models unless I break from the SDK and build the list manually.

Comment: @thom can you use the client and needed models without the need to reference the use and path? I think you are going at it from the atomic level vs using model objects provided from client and services

Comment: @thom you want to access this custom tab type right?

listCustomFields shown as json

"customFields": {
    "textCustomFields": [
      {
        "fieldId": "123",
        "name": "MYCustomID",
        "show": "false",
        "required": "false",
        "value": "myId012345"
      }
    ],
    "listCustomFields": [
      {
        "listItems": [
          "elementValue1","elementValue2","elementValue3"
        ],
        "fieldId": "1234",
        "name": "myArrayListofItems",
        "show": "false",
        "required": "false",
        "value": "3"
      }
    ]

Comment: I have tried to reference it inline when I need to create the new object and get the same error, because of the class name being a reserved name. No, I am already building custom tabs. That works fine. I am trying to build a drop-down list in a tab. The model "List" is causing the problem when trying to reference it.

Comment: @thom Thanks for the update, I suspect this question is incorrectly stated and that the real issue is more about what you are trying to accomplish, which is unclear and needs better definition. I am willing to help if you show us what "UI" element and behavior in DocuSign you are trying to achieve for the Sender or Signer. A larger segment of code and the actual json/soap that works, then we can get the PHP to do it I am sure.